# long table from R exceeds page width

Tags: margins, longtable

Any suggestions to fix a Tex table from R software that exceeds margins in the 12pts document class

Here my code and output :

```
     \documentclass[12pt]{article}
       \usepackage{geometry}
       \geometry{a4paper,left=15mm,right=15mm, top=1cm, bottom=2cm}
       \usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
        \usepackage{natbib}
       \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{color}
      \usepackage{multicol}
     \usepackage{setspace}
     \usepackage{varioref}
     \usepackage{booktabs}
     \usepackage{xfrac}
    \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amssymb}


 \begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Linear Mixed Effects Regression Results} 
   \label{tb:lme-main} 
  \tiny 
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{0.01pt}}lcccccc} 
    \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
   & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
  \cline{2-7} 
   & KAI-BASE & KAI-MSCI & KAI-RATINGS & KAO-BASE & KAO-MSCI & KAO-RATINGS \\ 
    \\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6)\\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag, baseline) & $-$0.003 & $-$0.006 & 0.019 & 0.030$^{*}$ & 0.040$^{*}$ & 0.068$^{**}$ \\ 
 & (0.013) & (0.016) & (0.020) & (0.013) & (0.017) & (0.021) \\ 
 Mean KAI: MSCI Peers (low, spatial lag) &  & 0.031 &  &  &  &  \\ 
 &  & (0.071) &  &  &  &  \\ 
 Mean KAI: MSCI Peers (medium, spatial lag) &  & 0.0003 &  &  &  &  \\ 
 &  & (0.080) &  &  &  &  \\ 
Mean KAI: Ratings Peers (low, spatial lag) &  &  & 0.028 &  &  &  \\ 
 &  &  & (0.040) &  &  &  \\ 
  Mean KAI: Ratings Peers (medium, spatial lag) &  &  & 0.010 &  &  &  \\ 
 &  &  & (0.033) &  &  &  \\ 
  msci\_kao\_tercile\_low &  &  &  &  & 0.055 &  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  & (0.063) &  \\ 
   msci\_kao\_tercile\_med &  &  &  &  & $-$0.015 &  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  & (0.072) &  \\ 
   Mean KAO: MSCI Peers (low, spatial lag) &  &  &  &  &  & 0.079$^{+}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.041) \\ 
   Mean KAO: MSCI Peers (medium, spatial lag) &  &  &  &  &  & 0.084$^{*}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.035) \\ 
  Mean KAO: Ratings Peers (low, spatial lag) & 0.131$^{***}$ & 0.141$^{***}$ & 0.123$^{**}$ & 
 0.246$^{***}$ & 0.247$^{***}$ & 0.204$^{***}$ \\ 
& (0.036) & (0.038) & (0.038) & (0.048) & (0.048) & (0.048) \\ 
    Mean KAO: Ratings Peers (medium, spatial lag) & $-$0.261$^{***}$ & $-$0.265$^{***}$ & $-$0.276$^{***}$ & $-$0.464$^{***}$ & $-$0.449$^{***}$ & $-$0.447$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.052) & (0.053) & (0.056) & (0.065) & (0.065) & (0.068) \\ 
   log(trade\_open\_lag) & $-$0.143$^{***}$ & $-$0.116$^{**}$ & $-$0.148$^{**}$ & $-$0.138$^{**}$ & $-$0.118$^{*}$ & $-$0.153$^{**}$ \\ 
  & (0.040) & (0.043) & (0.046) & (0.043) & (0.047) & (0.049) \\ 
   inflation\_lag & 0.001$^{***}$ & 0.001$^{***}$ & 0.0004$^{**}$ & 0.001$^{***}$ & 0.001$^{***}$ & 0.001$^{***}$ \\ 
     & (0.0001) & (0.0001) & (0.0002) & (0.0002) & (0.0002) & (0.0002) \\ 
        Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x MSCI Peers (low KAI) &  &  &  &  & $-$0.023 &  \\ 
   &  &  &  &  & (0.033) &  \\ 
        Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x MSCI Peers (medium KAI) &  &  &  &  & 0.005 &  \\ 
   &  &  &  &  & (0.040) &  \\ 
        Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x Ratings Peers (low KAI) &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.060$^{*}$ \\ 
     &  &  &  &  &  & (0.030) \\ 
       Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x Ratings Peers (medium KAI) &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.051$^{*}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.026) \\ 
              Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x MSCI Peers (low KAO) & $-$0.112 & $-$0.483 & 0.200 & 
    $-$1.433 & $-$1.694$^{+}$ & $-$0.482 \\ 
     & (0.733) & (0.778) & (0.819) & (0.933) & (0.955) & (1.030) \\ 
               Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x MSCI Peers (medium KAO) & 0.001$^{+}$ & 0.002$^{*}$ & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & $-$0.001 \\ 
   & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
                Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x Ratings Peers (low KAO) & $-$0.032 & $-$0.021 & $-$0.001 & $-$0.060$^{*}$ & $-$0.051$^{*}$ & $-$0.033 \\ 
    & (0.024) & (0.024) & (0.027) & (0.025) & (0.026) & (0.028) \\ 
      Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x Ratings Peers (medium KAO) & $-$0.007$^{+}$ & 
  $-$0.006$^{+}$ & $-$0.006 & 0.005 & 0.004 & 0.004 \\ 
             & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) \\ 
            Log Constant GDP (2010 USDB, lag) & 0.005 & 0.006 & 0.008 & 0.007 & 0.008$^{+}$ & 0.011$^{*}$ \\ 
    & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) \\ 
    Log Constant GDP per capita (2010 USD, lag) &  & 0.030 &  &  &  &  \\ 
   &  & (0.033) &  &  &  &  \\ 
    Trade (\% of GDP, log, lag) &  & 0.028 &  &  &  &  \\ 
    &  & (0.036) &  &  &  &  \\ 
    Inflation (annual \%, lag) &  &  & $-$0.049$^{+}$ &  &  &  \\ 
      &  &  & (0.029) &  &  &  \\ 
      Real Interest Rate (\%, lag) &  &  & $-$0.028 &  &  &  \\ 
       &  &  & (0.025) &  &  &  \\ 
      \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    Varying Intercept: Country & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
     Varying Intercept: Year & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
     Number of Countries & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 \\ 
     Number of Years & 21 & 20 & 20 & 21 & 20 & 20 \\ 
     Observations & 418 & 410 & 377 & 418 & 410 & 377 \\ 
     Log Likelihood & 155.597 & 153.257 & 126.733 & 130.218 & 123.183 & 106.594 \\ 
   Akaike Inf. Crit. & $-$285.195 & $-$272.513 & $-$219.467 & $-$234.435 & $-$212.366 & $-$179.187 \\ 
   Bayesian Inf. Crit. & $-$232.734 & $-$204.239 & $-$152.618 & $-$181.974 & $-$144.091 & $-$112.339 \\ 
   \hline 
   \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 \textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{6}{r}{In the interaction models, the first row presents results for which peers’ capital inflow/outflow restrictions are high. Standard errors in parentheses. $^{+}$p$<$0.1; $^{*}$p$<$0.05; $^{**}$p$<$0.01; $^{***}$p$<$0.001} \\ 
  \end{tabular} 
  \end{table} 
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing of table is demanding task ...

In your table I would use for columns with numbers `S` column type defined in `siunitx` package, for horizontal rules exploit `bootkabs` package (you load it twice!) and long text in the first column split onto two lines where needed. By this is given more space for other columns, consequently in table can be used `\small` font size.

For table I would use `tabularray` package, because table is huge I would format it as long table, for table notes use `tabularray` syntax:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            hmargin=15mm, vmargin={1cm,2cm}]{geometry}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[hang, font=small, 
            labelfont=bf,textfont=it]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    \NewTableCommand\SCR{\SetCell[r=2]{font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}}
    \sisetup{
        input-open-uncertainty =,
        input-close-uncertainty=,
        table-align-text-after=false,
        table-align-text-before=false
            }
      \ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewChildSelector{eachtwo}
      {
        \int_step_inline:nnnn {5}{2}{\l_tblr_childs_total_tl}
          { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tblr_childs_clist {##1} }
      }
    \ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    %\small
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Linear Mixed Effects Regression Results},
  label = {tb:lme-main},
 note{} = {In the interaction models, the first row presents results for which peers’ 
           capital inflow/outflow restrictions are high. Standard errors in parentheses.\newline
            $^{+}:\   p<0.1$; \quad 
            $^{*}:\   p<0.05$;\quad 
            $^{**}:\  p<0.01$;\quad 
            $^{***}:\ p<0.001$.}
                ]{rowhead= 4,
                  colsep = 3pt,
                  colspec = {@{} X[l] *{6}{Q[c, si={table-format=-1.4{\TblrNote{***}}}]} @{}},
                  row{5-Z} = {rowsep=0pt},
                  row{eachtwo} = {abovesep=4pt},
                  rows = {font=\small}
                 }
    \toprule
    & \SetCell[c=6]{c}  {{{\textit{Dependent variable:}}}}                                            
                 &            &                 &            &            &                     \\         
    \cline{2-7}
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    KAI 
                 &            &                 &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    KAO     
                                                             &            &                     \\   
    \cmidrule[r]{2-4}   \cmidrule[l]{5-7} 
    & {{{BASE}}} & {{{MSCI}}} & {{{RATINGS}}}   & {{{BASE}}} & {{{MSCI}}} & {{{RATINGS}}}       \\
    & {{{(1)}}}  & {{{(2)}}}  & {{{(3)}}}       & {{{(4)}}}  & {{{(5)}}}  & {{{(6)}}}           \\
    \midrule
Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag, baseline)
    & -0.003    & -0.006      & 0.019           & 0.030\TblrNote{*}
                                                            & 0.040\TblrNote{*} 
                                                                          & 0.068\TblrNote{*}   \\
    & (0.013)   & (0.016)     & (0.020)         & (0.013)   & (0.017)     & (0.021)             \\
 Mean KAI: MSCI Peers (low, spat. lag)
    &           & 0.031       &                 &           &             &                     \\
    &           & (0.071)     &                 &           &             &                     \\
 Mean KAI: MSCI Peers (medium, spat. lag) 
    &           & 0.0003      &                 &           &             &                     \\
    &           & (0.080)     &                 &           &             &                     \\
Mean KAI: Ratings Peers (low, spat. lag) 
    &           &             & 0.028           &           &             &                     \\
    &           &             & (0.040)         &           &             &                     \\
Mean KAI: Ratings Peers (medium, spat. lag) 
    &           &             & 0.010           &           &             &                     \\
    &           &             & (0.033)         &           &             &                     \\
msci\_kao\_tercile\_low 
    &           &             &                 &           & 0.055       &                     \\
    &           &             &                 &           & (0.063)     &                     \\
msci\_kao\_tercile\_med 
    &           &             &                 &           & -0.015      &                     \\
    &           &             &                 &           & (0.072)     &                     \\
Mean KAO: MSCI Peers (low, spat. lag) 
    &           &             &                 &           &             & 0.079\TblrNote{+}   \\
    &           &             &                 &           &             & (0.041)             \\
Mean KAO: MSCI Peers (medium, spat. lag) 
    &           &             &                 &           &             & 0.084\TblrNote{*}   \\
    &           &             &                 &           &             & (0.035)             \\
Mean KAO: Ratings Peers (low, spat. lag) 
    & 0.131\TblrNote{***} 
                & 0.141\TblrNote{***} 
                              & 0.123\TblrNote{**} 
                                                & 0.246\TblrNote{***} 
                                                            & 0.247\TblrNote{***} 
                                                                          & 0.204\TblrNote{***} \\
    & (0.036)   & (0.038)     & (0.038)         & (0.048)   & (0.048)     & (0.048)             \\
\SCR    {Mean KAO: Ratings Peers\\ (medium, spat. lag)} 
    & -0.261\TblrNote{***} 
                & -0.265\TblrNote{***} 
                              & -0.276\TblrNote{***} 
                                                & -0.464\TblrNote{***} 
                                                            & -0.449\TblrNote{***} 
                                                                          & -0.447\TblrNote{***}\\
    & (0.052)   & (0.053)     & (0.056)         & (0.065)   & (0.065)     & (0.068)             \\
log(trade\_open\_lag) 
    & -0.143\TblrNote{***} 
                & -0.116\TblrNote{**} 
                              & -0.148\TblrNote{**} 
                                                & -0.138\TblrNote{**} 
                                                            & -0.118\TblrNote{*} 
                                                                          & -0.153\TblrNote{**} \\
    & (0.040)   & (0.043)     & (0.046)         & (0.043)   & (0.047)     & (0.049)             \\
inflation\_lag 
    & 0.001\TblrNote{***} 
                & 0.001\TblrNote{***} 
                             & 0.0004\TblrNote{**} 
                                                & 0.001\TblrNote{***} 
                                                            & 0.001\TblrNote{***} 
                                                                          & 0.001\TblrNote{***} \\
     & (0.0001) & (0.0001)  & (0.0002)          & (0.0002)  & (0.0002)    & (0.0002)            \\
\SCR    {Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag)\\  \qquad$\times$  MSCI Peers (low KAI)} 
    &           &           &                   &           & -0.023      &                     \\*
    &           &           &                   &           & (0.033)     &                     \\
\SCR    {Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag)\\  \qquad$\times$  MSCI Peers (medium KAI)} 
    &           &           &                   &           & 0.005       &                     \\*
    &           &           &                   &           & (0.040)     &                     \\
\SCR    {Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag)\\  \qquad$\times$  Ratings Peers (low KAI)}
    &           &           &                   &           &             & -0.060\TblrNote{*}  \\*
    &           &           &                   &           &             & (0.030)             \\
\SCR    {Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag)\\  \qquad$\times$  Ratings Peers (medium KAI)}
    &           &           &                   &           &             & -0.051\TblrNote{*}  \\*
    &           &           &                   &           &             & (0.026)             \\
\SCR    {Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag)\\  \qquad$\times$  MSCI Peers (low KAO)} 
    & -0.112    & -0.483    & 0.200             & -1.433    & -1.694\TblrNote{+} 
                                                                          & -0.482              \\*
    & (0.733)   & (0.778)   & (0.819)           & (0.933)   & (0.955)     & (1.030)             \\
\SCR    {Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag)\\  \qquad$\times$  MSCI Peers (medium KAO)} 
    & 0.001\TblrNote{+} 
                & 0.002\TblrNote{*} 
                            & 0.001             & 0.001     & 0.001       & -0.001              \\*
   & (0.001)    & (0.001)   & (0.001)           & (0.001)   & (0.001)     & (0.001)             \\
\SCR    {Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag)\\  \qquad$\times$  Ratings Peers (low KAO)} 
    & -0.032    & -0.021    & -0.001            & -0.060\TblrNote{*} 
                                                            & -0.051\TblrNote{*} 
                                                                          & -0.033              \\*
    & (0.024)   & (0.024)   & (0.027)           & (0.025)   & (0.026)     & (0.028)             \\
\SCR    {Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag)\\  \qquad$\times$  Ratings Peers (medium KAO)} 
    & -0.007\TblrNote{+} 
                & -0.006\TblrNote{+} 
                            & -0.006            & 0.005     & 0.004       & 0.004               \\*
    & (0.004)   & (0.004)   & (0.004)           & (0.004)   & (0.004)     & (0.004)             \\
Log Constant GDP (2010 USDB, lag) 
    & 0.005     & 0.006     & 0.008             & 0.007     & 0.008\TblrNote{+} 
                                                                          & 0.011\TblrNote{*}   \\
    & (0.004)   & (0.004)   & (0.005)           & (0.005)   & (0.005)     & (0.005)             \\
Log Constant GDP per capita (2010 USD, lag) 
    &           & 0.030     &                   &           &             &                     \\
    &           & (0.033)   &                   &           &             &                     \\
Trade (\% of GDP, log, lag) 
    &           & 0.028     &                   &           &             &                     \\
    &           & (0.036)   &                   &           &             &                     \\
Inflation (annual \%, lag) 
    &           &           & -0.049\TblrNote{+}&           &             &                     \\
    &           &           & (0.029)           &           &             &                     \\
Real Interest Rate (\%, lag) 
    &           &           & -0.028            &           &             &                     \\
    &           &           & (0.025)           &           &             &                     \\
    \midrule
Varying Intercept: Country 
    & {{{Yes}}} & {{{Yes}}} & {{{Yes}}} & {{{Yes}}} & {{{Yes}}} & {{{Yes}}} \\
Varying Intercept: Year 
    & {{{Yes}}} & {{{Yes}}} & {{{Yes}}} & {{{Yes}}} & {{{Yes}}} & {{{Yes}}} \\
Number of Countries 
    & {{{25}}}  & {{{25}}}  & {{{25}}}  & {{{25}}}  & {{{25}}}  & {{{25}}} \\
Number of Years 
    & {{{21}}}  & {{{20}}}  & {{{20}}}  & {{{21}}}  & {{{20}}}  & {{{20}}} \\
Observations 
    & {{{418}}} & {{{410}}} & {{{377}}} & {{{418}}} & {{{410}}} & {{{377}}} \\
Log Likelihood 
    & {{{155.597}}}     & {{{153.257}}}     & {{{126.733}}} 
                        & {{{130.218}}}     & {{{123.183}}}     & {{{106.594}}}     \\
Akaike Inf. Crit. 
    & {{{-285.195}}}    & {{{-272.513}}}    & {{{-219.467}}} 
                        & {{{-234.435}}}    & {{{-212.366}}}    & {{{-179.187}}}    \\
Bayesian Inf. Crit. 
    & {{{-232.734}}}    & {{{-204.239}}}    & {{{-152.618}}} 
                        & {{{-181.974}}}    & {{{-144.091}}}    & {{{-112.339}}}    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such a wonderful contribution

Comment: @Haithem, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `threeparttable` to fix it because the main problem is the last column spans due to the last line Note.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=15mm,right=15mm, top=1cm, bottom=2cm}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{threeparttable}% <-- new

 \begin{document}
  \begin{threeparttable}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{Linear Mixed Effects Regression Results} 
   \label{tb:lme-main} 
    \tiny 
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}% <-- set column seperation
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{0.01pt}}lcccccc} 
    \\[-1.8ex]\hline 
    \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
   & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
  \cline{2-7} 
   & KAI-BASE & KAI-MSCI & KAI-RATINGS & KAO-BASE & KAO-MSCI & KAO-RATINGS \\ 
    \\[-1.8ex] & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6)\\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag, baseline) & $-$0.003 & $-$0.006 & 0.019 & 0.030$^{*}$ & 0.040$^{*}$ & 0.068$^{**}$ \\ 
 & (0.013) & (0.016) & (0.020) & (0.013) & (0.017) & (0.021) \\ 
 Mean KAI: MSCI Peers (low, spatial lag) &  & 0.031 &  &  &  &  \\ 
 &  & (0.071) &  &  &  &  \\ 
 Mean KAI: MSCI Peers (medium, spatial lag) &  & 0.0003 &  &  &  &  \\ 
 &  & (0.080) &  &  &  &  \\ 
Mean KAI: Ratings Peers (low, spatial lag) &  &  & 0.028 &  &  &  \\ 
 &  &  & (0.040) &  &  &  \\ 
  Mean KAI: Ratings Peers (medium, spatial lag) &  &  & 0.010 &  &  &  \\ 
 &  &  & (0.033) &  &  &  \\ 
  msci\_kao\_tercile\_low &  &  &  &  & 0.055 &  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  & (0.063) &  \\ 
   msci\_kao\_tercile\_med &  &  &  &  & $-$0.015 &  \\ 
  &  &  &  &  & (0.072) &  \\ 
   Mean KAO: MSCI Peers (low, spatial lag) &  &  &  &  &  & 0.079$^{+}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.041) \\ 
   Mean KAO: MSCI Peers (medium, spatial lag) &  &  &  &  &  & 0.084$^{*}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.035) \\ 
  Mean KAO: Ratings Peers (low, spatial lag) & 0.131$^{***}$ & 0.141$^{***}$ & 0.123$^{**}$ & 
 0.246$^{***}$ & 0.247$^{***}$ & 0.204$^{***}$ \\ 
& (0.036) & (0.038) & (0.038) & (0.048) & (0.048) & (0.048) \\ 
    Mean KAO: Ratings Peers (medium, spatial lag) & $-$0.261$^{***}$ & $-$0.265$^{***}$ & $-$0.276$^{***}$ & $-$0.464$^{***}$ & $-$0.449$^{***}$ & $-$0.447$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.052) & (0.053) & (0.056) & (0.065) & (0.065) & (0.068) \\ 
   log(trade\_open\_lag) & $-$0.143$^{***}$ & $-$0.116$^{**}$ & $-$0.148$^{**}$ & $-$0.138$^{**}$ & $-$0.118$^{*}$ & $-$0.153$^{**}$ \\ 
  & (0.040) & (0.043) & (0.046) & (0.043) & (0.047) & (0.049) \\ 
   inflation\_lag & 0.001$^{***}$ & 0.001$^{***}$ & 0.0004$^{**}$ & 0.001$^{***}$ & 0.001$^{***}$ & 0.001$^{***}$ \\ 
     & (0.0001) & (0.0001) & (0.0002) & (0.0002) & (0.0002) & (0.0002) \\ 
        Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x MSCI Peers (low KAI) &  &  &  &  & $-$0.023 &  \\ 
   &  &  &  &  & (0.033) &  \\ 
        Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x MSCI Peers (medium KAI) &  &  &  &  & 0.005 &  \\ 
   &  &  &  &  & (0.040) &  \\ 
        Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x Ratings Peers (low KAI) &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.060$^{*}$ \\ 
     &  &  &  &  &  & (0.030) \\ 
       Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x Ratings Peers (medium KAI) &  &  &  &  &  & $-$0.051$^{*}$ \\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.026) \\ 
              Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x MSCI Peers (low KAO) & $-$0.112 & $-$0.483 & 0.200 & 
    $-$1.433 & $-$1.694$^{+}$ & $-$0.482 \\ 
     & (0.733) & (0.778) & (0.819) & (0.933) & (0.955) & (1.030) \\ 
               Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x MSCI Peers (medium KAO) & 0.001$^{+}$ & 0.002$^{*}$ & 0.001 & 0.001 & 0.001 & $-$0.001 \\ 
   & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) & (0.001) \\ 
                Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x Ratings Peers (low KAO) & $-$0.032 & $-$0.021 & $-$0.001 & $-$0.060$^{*}$ & $-$0.051$^{*}$ & $-$0.033 \\ 
    & (0.024) & (0.024) & (0.027) & (0.025) & (0.026) & (0.028) \\ 
      Log Volatility (ARIMA, lag) x Ratings Peers (medium KAO) & $-$0.007$^{+}$ & 
  $-$0.006$^{+}$ & $-$0.006 & 0.005 & 0.004 & 0.004 \\ 
             & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.004) \\ 
            Log Constant GDP (2010 USDB, lag) & 0.005 & 0.006 & 0.008 & 0.007 & 0.008$^{+}$ & 0.011$^{*}$ \\ 
    & (0.004) & (0.004) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) & (0.005) \\ 
    Log Constant GDP per capita (2010 USD, lag) &  & 0.030 &  &  &  &  \\ 
   &  & (0.033) &  &  &  &  \\ 
    Trade (\% of GDP, log, lag) &  & 0.028 &  &  &  &  \\ 
    &  & (0.036) &  &  &  &  \\ 
    Inflation (annual \%, lag) &  &  & $-$0.049$^{+}$ &  &  &  \\ 
      &  &  & (0.029) &  &  &  \\ 
      Real Interest Rate (\%, lag) &  &  & $-$0.028 &  &  &  \\ 
       &  &  & (0.025) &  &  &  \\ 
      \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
    Varying Intercept: Country & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
     Varying Intercept: Year & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes & Yes \\ 
     Number of Countries & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 \\ 
     Number of Years & 21 & 20 & 20 & 21 & 20 & 20 \\ 
     Observations & 418 & 410 & 377 & 418 & 410 & 377 \\ 
     Log Likelihood & 155.597 & 153.257 & 126.733 & 130.218 & 123.183 & 106.594 \\ 
   Akaike Inf. Crit. & $-$285.195 & $-$272.513 & $-$219.467 & $-$234.435 & $-$212.366 & $-$179.187 \\ 
   Bayesian Inf. Crit. & $-$232.734 & $-$204.239 & $-$152.618 & $-$181.974 & $-$144.091 & $-$112.339 \\ 
   \hline 
   \hline
  \end{tabular} 
  \begin{tablenotes}% <-- this is the trick
    \item[] \textit{Note}: In the interaction models, the first row presents results for which peers’ capital inflow/outflow restrictions are high. Standard errors in parentheses. $^{+}$p$<$0.1; $^{*}$p$<$0.05; $^{**}$p$<$0.01; $^{***}$p$<$0.001.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable} 
\end{document}
```

In addition to that, set the column separation a little bit to fit the page.

[image: Result]

> It is always tedious to get the table to look right. Manual adjustment is often required.